# Dynamically read from command line and create objects

Tags: python, command-line, dynamically-generated

I want to dynamically read from the command line and convert the input to the right format. Therefore I have to determien the required type and instantiate such an object. Due input is `str` I have to convert the input correctly.
Here is an example what I want to do in pseudocode. If `TypeOf` fails it should raise an exception, maybe `ValueError`.

```
required_foo_type = 3.0
foo_input = Input("Enter foo: ")
bar = new TypeOf(required_foo_type, foo_input)
```

How can I do that in python?

Comment: A [python tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?&q=python+tutorial) could be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo_input = raw_input("Enter foo: ")

required_foo_type = float # aka type(3.0)
try:
     bar = required_foo_type(foo_input)
except TypeError:
     print "wrong input"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you start the Python tutorial first. It give you a quick start. 
Like this one: [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) Especially read the chapter 3 onward...

Jochen Ritzel has gave you a very good answer. :) But if you feel it's too advance,. Here is the easy one.

```
a = input("Enter a number: ") # return integer
b = raw_input("Enter any text") # return string
c = int(raw_input("Enter number: ")) # return string but converted to integer
d = float(raw_input("Enter float: ")) # return string but converted to float
```